# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/context/WorkoutContext.jsx?t=1672368719868' does not provide an export named 'WorkoutContextProvider'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

This is my 'WorkoutContext.jsx' file in context folder. This throws an error..

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/context/WorkoutContext.jsx?t=1672368719868' does not provide an export named 'WorkoutContextProvider'

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from 'react'

export const WorkoutsContext = createContext()

export const workoutsReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_WORKOUTS':
      return { 
        workouts: action.payload 
      }
    case 'CREATE_WORKOUT':
      return { 
        workouts: [action.payload, ...state.workouts] 
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export const WorkoutsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(workoutsReducer, { 
    workouts: null
  })
  
  return (
    <WorkoutsContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      { children }
    </WorkoutsContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `WorkoutsContextProvider` a default export:

```
const WorkoutsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(workoutsReducer, { 
    workouts: null
  })
  
  return (
    <WorkoutsContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      { children }
    </WorkoutsContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default WorkoutsContextProvider
```

then import it as:
`import WorkoutsContextProvider from "/context/WorkoutContext.jsx"`

You should read about javascript module imports and exports here: [Javascript Module Cheatsheet by Samantha Ming](https://medium.com/dailyjs/javascript-module-cheatsheet-7bd474f1d829)